# SQL Max value of pre-defined rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables: MEMBERS and POSTS. I need to make a query that will have following meaning:

Select all USERs that have some (>0) records in POSTS table =>
From them Select a USER who has the biggest ADS value in MEMBERS table.

I tried following thing:

```
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user=(select user from members where ads=(select Max(ads) from members))'
```

But this has a bug, that when USER with Max value in MEMBERS, has no records in POSTS table - SQL returns empty result.

My guess is that I should tell MySQL to choose Max value not from all rows, but only from pre-defined, but I don't know how to do it and if it's possible.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please show use the exact data model, including column types and constraints (PK and FK). Some example data and expected results could also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.*
FROM members AS m
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM posts AS p 
        WHERE p.member_id = m.member_id
      )
ORDER BY ads DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
   select m.member_id, max(p.ads)
     from members m
     join posts p 
       on m.member_id = p.member_id
    group by m.member_id
    order by max(p.ads) desc
    limit 1
```